# Is “far out” an outdated expression?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I learned “far out” means cool but have not seen the phrase in use (both in writing and verbal).

Is it an outdated expression?

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/far-out) calls it 'old-fashioned slang'!

Comment: Are you using it as an exclamation or adjective? Probably more acceptable to mean weird than good, as well.

Comment: How can this be anything but opinion-based? People who use it will say it is not dated, while those who do not use it will give the opposite answer. People who have not been exposed to as much English as others have will also give diverging answers to such questions.

Comment: I think “far out” is groovy, Man.

Comment: @tchrist : Opinion-based? Isn't that a matter of the question wording? How about: **Is *far out* (meaning *cool*) still in common usage?** (How to define *common* and map its usage to that is another matter.)

Answer (score 1):

It is current and [idiomatic](http://www.leadingout.net/australian-slang-25-essential-words-and-phrases/) in Australia as an expression of surprise.